# check if directory exists and delete in one command unix

Tags: unix

Is it possible to check if a directory exists and delete if it does,in Unix using a single command? I have situation where I use ANT 'sshexec' task where I can run only a single command in the remote machine. And I need to check if directory exists and delete it...

Comment: why not just use rmdir? if the directory does not exist, it will fail.

Comment: It will fail. And error in my ANT script. That will cause my build to crash.

Comment: Using `mkdir -p` will ignore errors if it already exists.

Comment: @Ferruccio- using rm -rf /dir_name does not throw a error but rm -rf  /dir_name throws says No such file or directory found. ( Just tested)

Comment: @remo bro you just posted the same command twice

Comment: What @remo was trying to say is, if you use the --force flag, even if the directory doesn't exist, there won't be an error.

Answer (score 230, accepted):

Assuming `$WORKING_DIR` is set to the directory... this one-liner should do it:

```shell
if [ -d "$WORKING_DIR" ]; then rm -Rf $WORKING_DIR; fi
```

(otherwise just replace with your directory)

Answer (score 311):

Why not just use `rm -rf /some/dir`?  That will remove the directory if it's present, otherwise do nothing. Unlike `rm -r /some/dir` this flavor of the command won't crash if the folder doesn't exist.

Comment: I think the original question was intended to mean: perform the delete only when file/directory exists or not. This command may work and produce similar results but actually doing a test before the command makes more sense.

Comment: @AnkurChauhan +1, I got warning if the dir does not exist.

Comment: This is not the answer for the question.

Comment: As stated above this isn't the answer.  One reason for testing before deleting would be inside a Jenkins job.  If the directory doesn't exist and you try to delete it, that will fail the job.  Checking beforehand is the better option.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. it does what @remo needs, i.e. deleting a directory only if it exists and not giving an error if it doesn't. Maybe the question is not quite well put because why would you need to check the existence when this command won't care?!

Comment: using this in an npm script and just using `rm dir` throws an error if the directory does not exist while `rm -rf dir` does not. so this answer definitely works

Comment: For those curious, `rm -rf nothing` returns status code `0` and does not write to `stderr` or `stdout`, so it should not cause any scripts or jobs to fail.

Comment: With -f there's no need for the test. It's the correct answer.

Comment: `rm -rf /some/dir` when the directory doesn't exist just shows `"rm: cannot remove '/some/dir': Is a directory"`. Seems to only happen when the directory has a dot in the name like `cdk.out/`.

Answer (score 39):

Try:

```
bash -c '[ -d my_mystery_dirname ] && run_this_command'
```

This will work if you can run bash on the remote machine....

In bash, `[ -d something ]` checks if there is directory called 'something', returning a success code if it exists and is a directory. Chaining commands with && runs the second command only if the first one succeeded. So `[ -d somedir ] && command` runs the command only if the directory exists.

Comment: Yes, and try it in a shell to make sure it's what you want.

Comment: First I want to see if it works locally and them I can send the command remotely. Am I looking at saying to check "/test" directory..just [ -d /test ] && mkdir /test ?

Comment: It should give an error if it exists, because it checks if the directory exists, and if yes it tries to create it. That's what it does for me (just tested). It shouldn't create a directory. Since you want to DELETE you probably need: `[ -d /test ] && rmdir /test` (or rm -rf /test if it isn't going to be empty and you want to delete all the contents)

Comment: @SineLaw: NOTE - It did not error when directory existed for me, and trying to create a directory! (tested it again). But for DELETE It does work. Please double check on that

Comment: sharma: are you using bash? what does 'echo $SHELL' say?

Answer (score 14):

Here is another one liner:

```
[[ -d /tmp/test ]] && rm -r /tmp/test
```

- && means execute the statement which follows only if the preceding
  statement executed successfully (returned exit code zero)

Comment: Not sure why, but `[ -d node_modules ] && rm -rf node_modules` failed to work with GitLab CI/CD Docker build, while it was happy with the version suggested by the accepted answer `if [ -d node_modules ]; then rm -rf node_modules; fi`

Comment: @Pjotr Did you include the double square brackets?  Your comment omitted them.  Double sets of brackets have a different meaning from single sets.

Comment: @cooperised No, I've had that with just a single set of brackets that seemed to work for me. Maybe that was why it kept failing on the GitLab CI/CD side. For some reason IDE did not like the double bracket variation either and was happy with the inline if.
I'd guess that my local system always had the node_modules present.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend opening documentation of [rm](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/rm1.html) command.
If open then you will see that there is a
`-f` flag does what you want. **Example**: `rm -f -R ./my_folder`